# ECU shielding/ Highway driving

Tags: exhaust, catalytic-converter, exhaust-manifold, aerodynamcs

Ok, two qs I was wondering about (completely unrelated):

1. How are ECUs and electronics shielded from all the heat that a car generates, especially when the car is driven in hotter climates (i.e Middle East, Africa)?
2. Since the catalytic converter and the exhaust pipe are at the bottom of most if not all cars obviously, does driving on the highway provide sufficient cooling to these parts due to convection from the moving air? Is it considerable cooling that engineers factor in when designing the car, its parts, and their respective operating temperatures?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So what do you think the under hood temperature gets to?

Most ecu's are put in an airstream and also sufficiently protected.

As for cats, the issue is making sure they stay sufficiently warm so the catalytic reactions occur. They are also shielded to try to avoid setting grass alight...